# How to set Link and Test Color and Properties for a New Div Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is My site
http://www.thesocietyguide.com/

I want to add a top menu like this site , the top one with signup now link in black background
http://www.thrillist.com/

I added a new class in css named Supertop, this is the code I used

```
#supertop {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#000000;
    text-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:none;
    link-color:#FFFFFF;

    }
```

But the link color without hover is almost black and with hover it shows red (LINK IS I THE RIGHT CORNER OF THE BLACK STRIP)

Please tell me what am I missing .
Also If someone can provide me the exact div class and fonts and color code the guy used on this site
http://www.thrillist.com/ 
It would be of great help and I can learn to add the properties from it

UPDATE******************
This is my site , I am making the bar here
[image]

This is the example site and the item which I want

[image]

Comment: #supertop is not class - it is id selector. Try with .supertop.

Comment: So Should I just replace the # with . ? When I did , the black strip which appeared is gone

Comment: Cant you get the styles by doing on the page  http://www.thrillist.com/

Comment: There is no such property as text-color or link-color. Apply 'color:#FFFFFF' to the anchor tag.

Comment: Dilip that does not works either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `color:#ffffff` to anchor tag should solve your problem.

```
#supertop a
{
 color:#ffffff;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#supertop a:hover
{
 color:#333;
}
```

The above css will be applied to all the anchor tags(links) inside the #supertop div.
If you don't want to use separate class for anchor tags you can use above css, though its not advisable.

Comment: Awesome :D
It worked and I was also able to move it to the left site, I used
#supertop a
{
 float: right;
}

But when I tried to add font by using
#supertop a
{
 font: bold;
}

it did not work , please tell me how to add fonts to it , also how can I define the hover color ?

Comment: Great. But you should understand all the answers here suggests standard practices across web. You can read about coding standards in html/css. You're welcome.

Comment: I was also able to move it to the left site, I used #supertop a { float: right; } But when I tried to add font by using #supertop a { font: bold; } it did not work , please tell me how to add fonts to it , also how can I define the hover color ?

Please provide me a link so I can read and learn all the tags I can use

Comment: w3schools.com will provide you with basic idea. Try discovering with chrome developer tools which you can open by pressing F12. You can edit any css property on the fly in chrome-dev-tools (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/). You should use `font-weight:bold` to make it bold.

Comment: Thank You , It worked as well I am going to study about it more , Thanks alot every body

Answer (score 0):

generally for targeting a hover item the code should look like :

```
#supertop:hover{color:yellow}
```

and also you could eventually target more specific items like `li > span`.

I don't see any menu in your site so I can't be more precise than this.

Comment: Check the update I posted on the question

Answer (score 0):

To get the text white, try adding a class (`sign-up-link` for example) to your `anchor` tag:

```
<a class="sign-up-link" href="http://hellol.com">Test</a> 

.sign-up-link {
color: #ffffff;
}
```

The red color http://www.thrillist.com/ is using on `hover` is `#b1000e`, so add:

```
.sign-up-link:hover {
color: #b1000e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not adding manual link items , I am styling a menu

Comment: You cant add a css class to the link?

Comment: I added a new menu , The signup link was added to the menu , I want to style the menu so that all the links added to it show like the example site

Comment: You can add this class to all the menus you're adding.

Comment: Dilip , I am adding the class already but  I want to edit the class , I want to make it like the example site, white bold link colors. How do I add properties to the div class ?

Comment: Initially you only had one link. One option is to add the css class to all links or simply add `#supertop a {color: #ffffff;}` to apply the style to all links under `#supertop`.